# Thumbnail height & width not being returned

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When performing a search request to the API, the height & width fields of the thumbnails are not included in the response, even when specified in the fields parameter. Here's an example for a JS object that provides the API parameters:

```
{
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    order: 'relevance',
    q: 'test',
    fields: 'items(snippet(thumbnails(high(url,height,width))))'
}
```

Which translates into the following request URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=relevance&part=snippet&q=test&fields=items(snippet(thumbnails(high(url%2Cheight%2Cwidth))))&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This call yields the following response without the width or height of the thumbnails.

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "thumbnails": {
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3HKs8WTGzw8/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "thumbnails": {
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vW_8K_mLtsU/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "thumbnails": {
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4Yk-jd4BHys/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "thumbnails": {
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HU9mnag7vSM/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "thumbnails": {
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pyrH7b0zHwU/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

This similarly does not work for the `default` or `medium` thumbnail keys either.

How can these fields be retrieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search endpoint won't return those details. You'll have to take the IDs returned from the search and do another API call to the [videos endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) for the snippet. For instance

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: The Youtube Data API v3 docs however claim this can be retrieved from the search endpoint: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search

Answer (score 0):

As per [Youtube Date API (v3) Search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) Method returns as per document but its not working properly.

Now you should try alternative method by the API call of Video.

URL :- https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

VIDEO_ID =  Return by Search API

YOUR_API_KEY = Google Project API key

Try it

```
$.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
            order:'relevance',
            part : 'snippet', 
            type : 'video',
            q: 'test',
            key: 'XXXXXXX'},
            function(data) {
               alert(data.items.length);
               $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                   pid = item.id.videoId;
                   getVids(pid);
               });
           }
         );

         //Get Videos
         function getVids(pid){
            $.get(
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",{
                 part : 'snippet', 
                 id : pid,
                 key: 'XXXXXXXX'},
                 function(data) {
                     //Code whatever you want 
                 }
             );
         }
```